# i want to delete the element even if user input is in small or Capital letter

Tags: python-3.x, list

```
nametoRemove = input("Enter the name you want to remove:")
print(nametoRemove)
name = ["Ramesh","Rakesh","Suresh"]
name.remove(nametoRemove)
print(name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it fith basic for loop and if statement:

```
nametoRemove = input("Enter the name you want to remove:")
print(nametoRemove)
name = ["Ramesh","Rakesh","Suresh"]
for item in name:
    if item.lower() == nametoRemove.lower():
        name.remove(item)
print(name)
```

output:

```
Enter the name you want to remove:ramesh
ramesh
['Rakesh', 'Suresh']
```